# TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0] when calling lil_matrix.diagonal() in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror, sparse-matrix

I try to get the sum of a diagonal of a sparse matrix stored in the [lil_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix) format with the following code:

```
sm1 = np.sum(board.diagonal(k=i1-row1))
sm2 = np.sum(board.diagonal(k=i2-row2))
```

however this gives me a

```
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

`type(board)` returns `<class 'scipy.sparse._lil.lil_matrix'>`

`row1, row2, i1, i2` are all integers.
The interesting things is if I call `print(np.sum(board.diagonal(k=i1-row1))` it prints the correct result before throwing the type error.

I suspect that the error is related to the conversion to a csr matrix, because `return self.tocsr().diagonal(k=k)` is mentioned in the error message and calling `board.tocsr()` throws the same error.

Thank in advance!

Here is the whole error log:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/285/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-professional/285/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/noah/PycharmProjects/nQueens/sa_sparse.py", line 94, in <module>
    y.run()
  File "/home/noah/PycharmProjects/nQueens/sa_sparse.py", line 63, in run
    self.swap(newSol)
  File "/home/noah/PycharmProjects/nQueens/sa_sparse.py", line 34, in swap
    newCost = self.calcFastCost(board.board, row1, row2)
  File "/home/noah/PycharmProjects/nQueens/sa_sparse.py", line 47, in calcFastCost
    sm1 = np.sum(board.diagonal(k=i1-row1))
  File "/home/noah/nQueens/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 1214, in diagonal
    return self.tocsr().diagonal(k=k)
  File "/home/noah/nQueens/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_lil.py", line 459, in tocsr
    _csparsetools.lil_get_lengths(self.rows, indptr[1:])
  File "_csparsetools.pyx", line 111, in scipy.sparse._csparsetools.lil_get_lengths
  File "_csparsetools.pyx", line 117, in scipy.sparse._csparsetools._lil_get_lengths_int32
  File "/home/noah/nQueens/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 345, in __len__
    raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

Comment: Could you show the full error with traceback?  Also what's the `dtype`.  Shape and nnz might help.  Ideally a small sample matrix as well, but that's probably too much..

Comment: @hpaulj I added the whole traceback. The dtype of `board` seems to be float64. The matrices are always some square permutation matrix (only 0 and 1). Thus nnz = n.

Comment: Don't use the LIL format for any reason. Problem solved. (Also update scipy)

Comment: Normally a `lil` should convert to `csr` without problem.  I'd have to look at the conversion code to see what could be causing the problem.  My first guess is that the lil is corrupted, with different length `data` and `rows` lists.

Comment: @CJR, if the `nQueens` is any clue, I suspect he's working with a modest size matrix, and modifying values a lot, or interactively.  `csr` is poor for changing sparsity, but required for things like finding the diagonal.  `lil` is great for row indexing, and no worse then `csr` for columns.

Comment: @hpaulj LIL is terrible for everything. Every nonzero value in the matrix has the memory overhead of two full python objects. You can't do any math with it. Random access is glacial. It's only even superficially useful because python preallocates a ton of memory for each list so you can add values without reallocating (which is why it's almost unusable on large problems). I firmly maintain that if you come to a situation where using this data structure makes any sense, you've made serious algorithm design errors.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `scipy` version?  In a current setup, I can make a `lil` and get the diagonal:

```
In [16]: M = sparse.lil_matrix(np.eye(3))
In [17]: M
Out[17]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in List of Lists format>    
In [18]: M.A
Out[18]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

No problem converting to `csr`, and no problem with diagonal:

```
In [19]: M.tocsr()
Out[19]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>    
In [20]: M.diagonal()
Out[20]: array([1., 1., 1.])
```

But asking `len`, does give your error:

```
In [21]: len(M)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [21], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 len(M)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py:291, in spmatrix.__len__(self)
    290 def __len__(self):
--> 291     raise TypeError("sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz()"
    292                     " or shape[0]")

TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]
```

For this `lil`, the other other steps are fine:

```
In [22]: M.nnz         
Out[22]: 3    
In [23]: M.getnnz()
Out[23]: 3
In [24]: M.shape
Out[24]: (3, 3)
```

lil stores values in two object dtype arrays:

```
In [26]: M.data
Out[26]: array([list([1.0]), list([1.0]), list([1.0])], dtype=object)
In [27]: M.rows
Out[27]: array([list([0]), list([1]), list([2])], dtype=object)
```

If I corrupt the matrix by dropping a `rows` element, I get a very different error.

It looks like the error occurs in `tocsr`, in this block, which is creating the `indptr` from the lengths of the `rows` elements:

```
    M, N = self.shape
    if M*N <= np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
        # fast path: it is known that 64-bit indexing will not be needed.
        idx_dtype = np.int32
        indptr = np.empty(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
        indptr[0] = 0
        _csparsetools.lil_get_lengths(self.rows, indptr[1:])
        np.cumsum(indptr, out=indptr)
        nnz = indptr[-1]
```

`lil_get_lengths` is compiled code that goes through the elements of `rows` and puts their lengths in the 2nd argument.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using scipy 1.8.1. My main motivation behind using lil was that I needed to swap a lot of rows, maybe I did something wrong there. I tried it with csr and convert it to coo to swap rows and convert it back to csr. This seems to work.